# Taskbar Icon Changes The First Time I Run The Program But Not After

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, icons, taskbar

I am trying to change my program's taskbar at run-time.

When I run the program from the IDE everything works fine. I have my icons in the resources area and I am setting them like so:

```
this.Icon = Properties.Resources.Green;
```

When I publish my program the first time it is installed my icons show. If I close the program and run it again I just see a default white icon.

It seems to only work once. The only way I can get it working is by uninstalling it and then installing it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Settings.Default instead

```
this.Icon = Properties.Settings.Default.Green;
```

Comment: It says Settings does not contain a definition for 'Green'.

Comment: You have to define it in the Settings file. MS VS can do it pretty easy for you.